# Compile Multiple PDF using RMarkdown LaTex Error

Tags: r, pdf, render, kable, kableextra

I am trying to automatically compile multiple individual PDF reports from RMarkdown using a for loop in a separate R script. There appears to be an issue using the `kable_styling()` function from the `kableExtra` package when compiling multiple reports, but not for a single report. 
This is the render loop in a separate script:

```
mtcars = data.frame(mtcars)
for (car in unique(rownames(mtcars))){
  rmarkdown::render('mtcars_report.Rmd',  # file 2
                    output_file =  paste("report_", car, ".pdf"))
}
```

Here is the YAML header used for all reports:

```
title: "mtcars_report"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}
  - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  - \usepackage{makecell}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
geometry: margin=.8cm
```

This RMD code works with this loop and renders each PDF:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

mtcars = data.frame(mtcars)

cars = mtcars[rownames(mtcars)==car,]


{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}

cars_table = cars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl)%>%
  t() %>%
  kable("latex") 

cars_table
```

This add a kable_styling command, the PDFs do not render:

```
cars_table = cars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl)%>%
  t() %>%
  kable("latex") %>%
 kable_styling(latex_options=c("striped", "float_right", "hold_position"),full_width = FALSE)

cars_table
```

I get this error: ! Undefined control sequence.
 \rowcolor

If I knit the RMD as a single file without the loop (i.e. `cars = mtcars[rownames(mtcars)=="Merc 280",]` it DOES work with the `kable_styling` . **It just appears to be an issue when I try to render it with the loop.** I have updated all packages to my knowledge running:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)  # update R packages
tinytex::tlmgr_update()  # update LaTeX packages
```

Comment: Maybe try putting your car filter in the yaml header as a parameter.https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html%23parameter_types%2F

Comment: I tried something along those lines but wasn't able to figure out how to knit multiple PDF using the params$ with the loop. I'm trying to automate the process for many PDFs at once. When I used the params I had to change each one manually each time to produce the different report.